# User-defined conversion-operator in nested class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading, conversion-operator

Why does the following code not compile:

```
struct X
{
    struct B;

    struct A
    {
        int dummy;
        operator B();
    };

    struct B
    {
        int dummy;
    };
};

X::A::operator B()
{
    B b;
    return b.dummy = dummy, b;
}
```

My MSVC++ 2017 compiler says:

```
error C2833: 'operator B' is not a recognized operator or type
```

Comment: Your code is accepted by both Clang and GCC. My bet is on a MSVC compiler bug.

Comment: CinCount, no, there are also user-defined conversion-operators.

Comment: Yep, [works fine on Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ad684a2c299ddcb). No idea where the downvotes come from.

Comment: Not sure if you can report via Microsoft Connect, but you can report it here: (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/62/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

The only possible reason of this error is that `struct B` is not defined-yet at the point when `struct A` is being defined. Since the code does not seem the be buggy, my conclusion is that you have found a compiler bug.

Answer (score 1):

Even though `B` *should* be looked up in the scope of `X` as the user defined conversion operator is being defined, MSVC seems to bungle it up.

You can give it hand by fully qualifying it:

```
X::A::operator X::B()
{
    B b;
    return b.dummy = dummy, b;
}
```